# Can I hash a UUID for higher entropy - Python

Tags: python, random, token, uuid, entropy

If I generate a UUID with something like

```
ID = uuid.uuid4()
```

I get a 128 bit string with 122 bits of entropy.

However I desire a string with more than 128 bits of entropy.

How will the entropy of the string change if I put this uuid through a hashing function.

for instance:

```
ID = uuid.uuid4()
ID = HASHFUNC(ID)
```

or even:

```
ID = uuid.uuid4()
Salt = someString
ID = HASHFUNC(ID+Salt)
```

Is it better to simply use os.urandom(32) and be done with it?

Thanks for the help

Comment: If you want to safely generate string tokens in python, you need to use the `secrets` module. Posting it as a comment since your question is specific about UUID, but I believe you're in the wrong path.

Comment: Nothing you do to transform your result will increase the entropy. You have to generate more random bits with a separate RNG process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't.

Although hashing a string with 2<sup>122</sup> possible values will give you a 128-bit result, there are still only 2<sup>122</sup> possible outcomes, so your hashed UUIDs still only carry 122 bits of information each.

Either use `os.urandom(16)` (since 16 bytes is sufficient for 128 bits of entropy), or the [`secrets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) module (if you're using Python 3.6).